# How to get the week day within a week of given date?

Tags: .net, nodatime

The question may not be the clearest one but here is what I needed:

```
var date = new LocalDate(2020, 05, 05);
```

I need a date for Monday and Friday of the week in which the given date is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest writing the code as a *date adjuster*:

```cs
public static class DayOfWeekAdjusters
{
    public static Func<LocalDate, LocalDate> ForIsoDayOfWeek(IsoDayOfWeek dayOfWeek) =>
        date => WeekYearRules.Iso.GetLocalDate(
            WeekYearRules.Iso.GetWeekYear(date),
            WeekYearRules.Iso.GetWeekOfWeekYear(date), 
            dayOfWeek);
}
```

Then you can use:

```cs
private static readonly Func<LocalDate, LocalDate> MondayAdjuster =
    DayOfWeekAdjusters.ForIsoDayOfWeek(IsoDayOfWeek.Monday);
private static readonly Func<LocalDate, LocalDate> FridayAdjuster =
    DayOfWeekAdjusters.ForIsoDayOfWeek(IsoDayOfWeek.Friday);

...
var date = new LocalDate(2020, 05, 05);
var monday = date.With(MondayAdjuster);
var friday = date.With(FridayAdjuster);
```

You can use those adjusters with `LocalDateTime` and `OffsetDateTime` too.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've come up with:

```
void Main()
{
    var date = new LocalDate(2020, 05, 05);
    var yearWeek = WeekYearRules.Iso.GetWeekOfWeekYear(date);
    var monday = WeekYearRules.Iso.GetLocalDate(date.Year, yearWeek, IsoDayOfWeek.Monday);
    var friday = WeekYearRules.Iso.GetLocalDate(date.Year, yearWeek, IsoDayOfWeek.Friday);
    Console.WriteLine(monday);
    Console.WriteLine(friday);
}
```

Or you can extract this logic into an extension method so you get:

```
void Main()
{   
    var date = new LocalDate(2020, 05, 05);
    var monday = date.GetDateOfWeekDay(IsoDayOfWeek.Monday);
    var friday = date.GetDateOfWeekDay(IsoDayOfWeek.Friday);
    Console.WriteLine(monday);
    Console.WriteLine(friday);
}

public static class LocalDateTimeExtensions {
    // I coudn't come up with better name for this function, if you have any suggestions... :)
    public static LocalDate GetDateOfWeekDay(this LocalDate date, IsoDayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
    {
        var currentWeekYear = WeekYearRules.Iso.GetWeekOfWeekYear(date);
        return WeekYearRules.Iso.GetLocalDate(date.Year, currentWeekYear, dayOfWeek);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you shouldn't use `date.Year` - you need to use the week year (and your `currentWeekYear` is really `currentWeekOfWeekYear`).

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this :). I see that `date.Year` and `WeekYearRules.Iso.GetWeekYear(date)` for January 1st return different results for some of the years (2011, 2012, 2016, 2017). The days of the week for those results are always Friday, Saturday and Sunday. Is there anywhere a good explanation of why is it like this?

Comment: Because ISO weeks are based on there being 4 days within that week-year. If the year starts on a Friday, Saturday or Sunday, that means that start of the year belongs to the previous week-year, because there aren't 4 days of the new year within the same week.

Comment: The documentation at https://nodatime.org/3.0.x/api/NodaTime.Calendars.WeekYearRules.html#NodaTime_Calendars_WeekYearRules_Iso is a bit better written :)